# Laravel model strange behaviour

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

Just curious why.

```
 public function get_number() {

    if(Model::get()->isEmpty()) {

        $number = Model::create(['number' => '1111111111']);

        $nubmer = $number->number; //(returns a... model, that's a suprise for me)

    } else {

        $number = Model::orderBy('number', 'desc')->first()->number;

        $number = Model::create(['number' => $number+1]);

        $number = $number->number; //(returns a property 1111111112 etc).

    }

return $number;
```

In both cases I am trying to get a property of a Model:

```
$number = $number->number;
```

But when "If" part works, it return a model (not property)...
when "else" part works, it returns a property (what i expected).

It means I don't understand something in Laravel:)

Why does it return a full Model in "If" case?:)

Comment: There is a typo error in the if condition `nubmer`. You are returning model in the first case as you are never overriding the original value of the `number` variable.

Comment: Thankyou) so stupid)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` block contains a typo:

```
public function get_number() {

if(Model::get()->isEmpty()) {

    $number = Model::create(['number' => '1111111111']);

    // this should be $number
    // $nubmer = $number->number;
    // change it to
    $number = $number->number;

} else {

    $number = Model::orderBy('number', 'desc')->first()->number;

    $number = Model::create(['number' => $number+1]);

    $number = $number->number; //(returns a property 1111111112 etc).

}
```

You also don't need to be assigning `$number = $number->number;`, simply return:

```
return $number->number;
```

Example:

```
public function get_number() {
    if(Model::get()->isEmpty()) {
        $number = Model::create(['number' => '1111111111']);
    } else {
        $number = Model::orderBy('number', 'desc')->first()->number;
        $number = Model::create(['number' => $number+1]);
    }

    return $number->number;
}
```